# What's the significance that Amasiah was singled out as a volunteer in 2 Chronicles 17:16?

Tags: 2-chronicles

2 Chronicles 17 lists Jehoshaphat's commanders and soldiers:

> 15 next, Jehohanan the commander, with 280,000;
> 16 next, Amasiah son of Zikri, who **volunteered** himself for the service of the Lord, with 200,000.

What's the significance that Amasiah was a volunteer while others were not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding this frustratingly brief account in 2 Chron 17:16 is by contrasting it with what surrounds it.

In 2 Chron 17:14-19 we have a five list of "commanders of thousands", a title that might be equivalent to "general" or, "major general" in a modern army: Adnah, Jehohanan, **Amasiah**, Eliaha, Jehozabad.

Only Amasiah is described as a "volunteer" implying that the others were professionally paid.  However, Amasiah was presumably wealthy enough to be able to refuse his salary and benefits but offered his services to the king and country at no cost.

This was truly a noble act.  Maclauren offers these comments:

> This is a scrap from the catalogue of Jehoshaphat’s ‘mighty men of
> valour’; and is Amasiah’s sole record. We see him for a moment and
> hear his eulogium and then oblivion swallows him up. We do not know
> what it was that he did to earn it. But what a fate, to live to all
> generations by that one sentence!

Answer (score 1):

#### What's the significance that Amasiah was singled out as a volunteer in 2 Chronicles 17:16?

First, the scriptures have no further information on this individual; in fact, this is the only occurrence of this name (not to be confused with Amaziah).

As to why this individual is singled out is only conjecture and speculation. But let's look at some commentaries:

[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/2_chronicles/17.htm)

> Who willingly offered himself unto the  Lord.—([Judges 5:2](https://biblehub.com/judges/5-2.htm);  [Judges 5:9](https://biblehub.com/judges/5-9.htm).) An allusion to some noble act of self-devotion, which was doubtless more fully recorded in the source from which the chronicler has drawn this brief account. Such allusions, though no longer intelligible, are important as conducing to the proof of the historical value of the narratives in which they occur.

[MacLaren's Expositions](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/maclaren/2_chronicles/17.htm)

> This is a scrap from the catalogue of Jehoshaphat’s ‘mighty men of valour’; and is Amasiah’s sole record. We see him for a moment and hear his eulogium and then oblivion swallows him up. We do not know what it was that he did to earn it. But what a fate, to live to all generations by that one sentence!

[Pulpit Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/2_chronicles/17.htm)

> Verse 16. - Amaziah, the son of Zichri. This man is not titled at all. The description of him as one who had willingly offered himself unto the Lord, not elucidated by the context or any effective parallel, will mark something honorable in his history. Possibly he comes from an unexpected quarter, and is a man of approved skill.

Answer (score 1):

As we read the text this mighty man of valor stands out in his service to the Lord and the people of Judah. Amasiah freely gave himself to the Lord. This is in contrast to the other men of valor who are named in this chapter. Only Amasiah freely gave- with no expectations- of himself and his men to serve the Lord. He stand out, not because of his might, but rather because of his heart to serve the Lord. May we be the Amasiah’s of our day- to freely give, to freely serve the God of the universe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).